# Tenant Creation in Azure portal using azure powershell commands or powershell API or ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template, azure-cli

Is It possible to create a tenant in azure subscription with azure powershell commands or powershell API.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is impossible currently.

Besides, the tenant is not in the subscription, the structure is the subscription in the tenant.